# How to request origin and body of a request in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm building a REST API using Java and Spring and I need to handle a POST request in my controller, but I need to extract the body from that request which is a JSON and also the "origin" of that request,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public XXX createMyObject(@RequestBody String data, YYY){
   MyObject mo = new MyObject();
   mo.setData = data;
   mo.setOrigin = yyy;

   myRepository.save(mo);
   return XXX;
}
```

I have a few questions: First is how can I obtain the origin of that request( which I guess is an url that travels in the header?), is there a similar annotation as the @RequestBody for that?.

My second question is what is usually the proper object to return in these kind of post methods as a response.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. If you include `HttpServletRequest` in your method parameters you will be able to get the origin information from there. eg.

   ```
   public XXX createMyObject(@Requestbody String data, HttpServletRequest request) {
           String origin = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN);
           //rest of code...
   ```

   }
2. For rest responses you will need to return a representation of the object (json) or the HttpStatus to notify the clients whether the call wass successful or not. eg
   `Return ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ok);`

Comment: You can even use `HttpHeaders.ORIGIN` constant.

Comment: I always get NULL

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get headers and uris from HttpServletRequest object

```
public XXX createMyObject(@RequestBody String data, HttpServletRequest request)
```

As for response I'd say return String which would be a view name to which you can pass some attributes saying that operation was successful or not, or ModelAndView.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

You can declare request object and then access in method to get Uri

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public XXX createMyObject(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String body) {
    String origin = URI.create(request.getRequestURL().toString()).getHost();
    System.out.println("Body: " + body + " Origin:" + origin);
    return XXX;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the request URL a bit different from the HTTP `origin` header? One should be the source address of the request, the other one the website domain which initiates the request?